# Why is the click of a button inside a Modal not opening another Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

We have a [modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) nesting a button inside it. On click of which we're ***trying*** to (generate at run-time and) open another modal like this:

```
  var createPrintableTable = function(divToAppendTo, newTableId) {
    $("#printer").remove();
    var tbl = $("<table style='display:block;' border='1'/>").attr("id", newTableId);
    var modal = $("<div id='printModal' class='modal' role='dialog' />");
    var modalDialog = "<div class='modal-dialog' />";
    var modalContent = "<div class='modal-content' />";
    var modalBody = "<div class='modal-body' />";
    $(modalBody).html('test modal body');
    $("#" + divToAppendTo).append(modal);
    $(modal).append(modalDialog);
    $(modalDialog).append(modalContent);
    $(modalContent).append(modalBody);
    $(modalBody).append(tbl);
    $(".modal-body").append("<button id='printer' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#printModal' style='float: right; top: -33px; right:40px; position: relative;border: none; font-size: 20px; color: #7f7f7f; background-color: #f8f8f8;'> <i class='fa fa-print' aria-hidden='true'></i> </button>");

    $("#printer").click(function() {
      debugger;
      $("#" + newTableId).css('display', 'block');
      $(modal).modal('show');
    });
  }

  createPrintableTable("myModal", "myModalTable");
```

It doesn't throws any error on the console but also doesn't open another modal. Where are we wrong here?

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/7s12b776/13/)

Comment: Can you create a working example? snippet/jsfiddle/something...

Comment: @Dekel Give me some time please

Comment: Sure :) no problem. Next time it's better to do it before posting, this way you will probably get quicker answer

Comment: Have you confirmed that the new modal HTML/DOM content is actually getting to the page?

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Nope, the DOM elements are not generating

Comment: Then that means that the selector `$("#" + divToAppendTo)` does not select anything. Make sure that `divToAppendTo` is set correctly.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Give me one minute, I'll quickly check

Comment: I don't see in the first modal a button to open the second modal

Comment: @Dekel I'm sorry, It's getting generated by the javascript code and need fontAwesome reference, please refresh the fiddle

Comment: Working on the explanation for why this happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you always use jQuery objects (and not strings) when you need to append elements:

```
var modal = $("<div id='printModal' class='modal' role='dialog' />");
var modalDialog = $("<div class='modal-dialog' />");
var modalContent = $("<div class='modal-content' />");
var modalBody = $("<div class='modal-body' />");
```

Otherwise the new elements are not appended to the elements you think you append them :)

2. When you did the `$(modal).modal('show');` - it actually did show, but the click (outside that modal) caused it to close immediately.
   This we can solve using the `setTimeout` on the `show`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(modal).modal('show');
}, 0)
```

Here is the final version:
https://jsfiddle.net/atggf59p/

Comment: Will appreciate also a vote-up on the answer (the up-arrow you have on the left).

Comment: Damn, this is perfect man!! Thanks :) I don't have privilege to upvote this :( which I wanted to

Comment: You do :) (as of a minute ago...)